# All windows decorations disappear after I maximize any window

Tags: 11.10, unity, window-decoration

When I maximize some of the windows all decorations disappear (by all, I mean on all windows)... Is that common issue on Unity or I'm just unlucky to have some prone to that bug configuration? Anyone have idea how to fix this?

It won't fix after unmaximize. It seems like maximazing window simply crashes window decorator. Decoration isn't displayed for all existing windows and any new ones. Only way I found to fix this is to run `compiz --replace` (but this ruins current windows placement - all windows end up on same desktop).

It happens almost every time I maximize window.

Comment: I havent seen this issue but some things you could explain to help narrow down the issue are: can you attach a screenshot? Is this reproducible? Does it get fixed after you unmaximize, or does it stay the same way? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Open the terminal and type
unity --reset

Comment: @tachyons IT LITERALLY DELETED EVERY UNITY SETTING I MADE EVER! YOU COULD AT LEAST WARN WHAT IT DOES!!!

Comment: it will delete some compiz settings ,but you can re-enable it via ccsm

Comment: You could also try Unity 2D and see if that happens too

Comment: it seems that after `unity --reset` it works fine (it reseted all my settings). But now I don't know which setting caused problem... I guess I will have to figure it out somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have begun experiencing this very recently(yesterday) as well. Going into compiz settings manager and unchecking "windows decorations", then re-checking it, seems to "fix" it, although it does continue to happen, causing me to have to open up compiz fairly often. Hopefully a fix will be found soon.

Edit!:
Fixed this issue for myself by entering Compiz Settings (CCSM), going into the Window Decorations menu, and changing the Command setting from:

```
gtk-window-decorator --replace
```

to:

```
/usr/bin/compiz-decorator
```

Backing out of this menu, then unchecking Window Decoration, allowing the desktop to reload, then checking Window Decoration and exiting out of CCSM.

After doing this, I've tested multiple applications, in various combinations of maximizing, minimizing, re-sizing, opening, closing, etc and can no longer reproduce the issue. The titlebar and everything stay exactly as they are supposed to. I don't remember ever changing this setting personally, though it is possible I did at some point, or gave compiz permission to while messing with another setting, but for me this has seemingly fixed the issue. Hopefully it will help you as well.

Comment: Well it seems that `unity --reset` (tachyons comment below my question) left `/usr/bin/compiz-decorator` there too... However it is nice to know how to fix this without losing all my settings :) I'm also not 100% sure if there was `gtk-window-decorator --replace` there before, but I don't want to risk messing around it to check if issue is linked with it in my case too...

Comment: I know I had been trying to set up the infamous "cube" in my case, just before I started having these problems, and then trying to get things back, and I changed and unchanged a number of compiz settings in this process, often with it saying things like , "This will cause such-and-such conflict. Resolve conflict?" and me being foolish enough to click yes without first learning what was going to be changed. So I am imagining that in that process I agreed to something which changed that setting. This is, of course, conjecture at this point.